# "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm a Python newbie. What I wanted to do was calculate the differences between float numbers. Differences must be between the number after and the number before. So first difference must be between 2nd number and last number. Here's my code:

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

i = 0
for i in x:
    difference = x[i+1] - x[i-1]
    print(difference)
```

And I get "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float".

Comment: The index `i` of a list is 0, 1, ..., N-1, where N is the length of the list. Then you get the value on the index `i` by `x[i]`. You source can be modified as ```for i in range(len(x)-1): print(x[i+1]-x[i])```. BTW, why do you use `+` for `difference`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your original question, when doing `for x in list`, `x` is the item in the list, not the index. That's why you get the TypeError.
(alsoI am wondering "difference" means subtract but not adding?)

Here is a working solution according to your question:

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

differencs = []
for i in range(len(x)):  # i = 0, 1, ..., x-1 
    before_idx = i-1
    after_idx = (i+1) % len(x)   # handle when i+1 exceeds the list length
    diff = x[after_idx] + x[before_idx]   # Please double check whether you need '+' or '-'
    differences.append(diff)

print(differences)
```

or the short version (using list comprehension):

```
differences = [x[(i+1)%len(x)] + x[i-1] for i in range(len(x))]

print(differences)
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case `i` is the value. So doing +1 or -1 you change the value. You meant to use the index. You can use `enumerate` (which gives you the index/value as tuple or `range`.

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

i = 0
for index, value in enumerate(x):
    difference = x[index+1] + x[index-1]
    print(difference)
```

**Note this still does not work**. You need some check to make sure you don't go out of bounds (the +1 and -1)

Answer (score 0):

Indexes should be integers only.

In your case, you used float values as the indexes.

`for i in loop` picks up the values from the list wherease `for i in range` picks up the indexes.
Please use following:

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]
for i in range(0,len(x)-1):
    difference = x[i+1] + x[i-1]
    print(difference)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for i in x:` returns every element of `x` as `i`, what you want is something like

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
    difference = x[i+1] + x[i-1]
    print(difference)
```

But probably this still doesn't yield what you're expecting to get. Assuming you want to get the difference between two consequtive elements do

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

for i in range(0, len(x)-1):
    difference = x[i+1] - x[i]
    print(difference)
```

Comment: It might be the OP's intention to find centred differences (next element minus previous element). There is nothing wrong with `x[i+1] - x[i-1]` _per se_, although in that case the loop should start at 1, as the result with `i=0` would be a valid expression but not what is intended.

Comment: In any case, I suggest deleting the redundant `i=0` before the loop.

Comment: Yes, it was just an assumption, but still you would have to subtract instead of adding, but that's a detail. Agreed with the uneccessary `i`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is iterating over the elements of "x". What you want is to iterate over the indices of "x". And you should "-" to find the difference. You can use the following code:

```
x = [811.91, 796.04, 796.14, 796.50, 796.81]

for i in range(1,len(x)):
    difference = x[i] - x[i-1]
    print(difference)
```

Comment: No, you need to loop from 1. On the first iteration, you get a `x[1] - x[-1]` (the second element minus the last element), which although is an expression that can be evaluated, is clearly not the intention. The aim is obviously to produce centred differences.  Also it would be good to remove the redundant `i=0` before the loop.